# How to add custom data-attribute in JQuery select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am populating the data in my select2 through ajax and I'm passing the id and text as the requirement of select2, but, I wanted to add some value in data-attributes. here is the data that I'm passing from php to ajax.

```
{
id: 1,
ws_header_id: 45, 
ws_collection_header_id: 1,
text: "Some Texts", 
}
```

and here is my ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: serverUrl,
                method: "GET",
                cache:false,
                data: bodyData,
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {

                    if(result){

                        console.log(result);
                        $(".working-schedule-id-select2").select2({data: result});

                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                }
            });
```

I wanted to add the `ws_header_id` to some custom data-ws-header-id attribute in the `<option>` tag.

Comment: Add your jstree code too or better if create a demo.

Comment: @Justcode how to add the jstree?

Comment: do you want to add new item dynamically ? or for example add from api?